# Accessing variable from enclosing scope in nested function

Tags: python, scope, closures

I have nested a function definition `bar()` inside another function `foo()`. Now I am trying to access a variable located in the outer function `foo()` from the nested function `bar()`. This however doesn't work because of the scoping rules (see error traceback below).

I am looking for something similar to the `global` keyword, which however only enables me to access *global* variables, whereas this is some kind of *semi-global* variable.

Here's example code:

```
def foo():
    i = 0
    def bar():
        # how can I get access to the variable from enclosing scope?
        i += 1
    bar()

foo()
```

The output is:

```
$ python test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 7, in <module>
    foo()
  File "test.py", line 5, in foo
    bar()
  File "test.py", line 4, in bar
    i += 1
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'i' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Please explain the reason for doing it. This will help us to give better solutions

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need the `nonlocal` statement instead of `global`.

`i` is clearly not global, but it is also not local to `foo`. It is local to `__init__`. Thus, in order to access it, declare it `nonlocal`.

Unfortunately, `nonlocal` ist python3 only.
You can simulate it via closure, but that'd get pretty ugly.

Comment: apparantly `nonlocal` is only available for Python 3.x , but this was a great search keyword.

Answer (score 3):

Here is your work around:

```
class Test(object):
    def __init__(self):
        i = [0]
        def foo():
            i[0] += 1
        foo()
        print i[0]

t = Test()
```

This would be a use case for the `nonlocal` keyword, instead of `global` but that is only available as of Python 3.

Comment: +1 for the Python 2.x workaround. Surprisingly container types are unaffected from this.

Comment: They *are* affected. What saves you here, is that the scoping rules DO allow READ access. Technically, you do not WRITE to i, you write to i[0]...

Comment: Interesting, found [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/293097/1025391) to explain this very well.